# Shell script to move files and rename it with index

Tags: linux, shell-script, rename, programming, move

Consider two directories `A` and `B`.

`A` contains a text file `A.txt` which changes its contents every 3 seconds.

The shell script is to move `A.txt` to directory `B` and rename it to `A_1.txt`.

After 3 seconds the script should copy `A.txt` as `A_2.txt` in directory `B`.

The script should not die until a delimiter is pressed.

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 2):

Using `bash` or `ksh93` and `inotifywait`:

```
i=0
while true; do
    inotifywait -e close_write A/A.txt
    cp A/A.txt "B/A_$(( ++i )).txt"
done
```

The script terminates when <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> is pressed.

Note: Since I'm not on Linux, I can't get `inotifywait` on my machine to actually catch the `close_write` event, but I'm hoping it will do so properly on Linux.

The call to `inotifywait` will return as soon as an external process, which has opened the file `A/A.txt` for writing, finishes writing and closes the file. This allows the script to carry on with copying the file to the `B` directory.

Doing it this way is more convenient than trying to synchronize the script with a process that writes to the file every once in a while.

Comment: works fine for me, though `inotifywait` is rather verbose, so maybe use `inotifywait -qq`